# Can HtmlUnit 2.15 connect using TLS instead of SSL?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, htmlunit, tls1.2

I have a `Java` application that connects to a web page using `HtmlUnit 2.15` and scrapes content of it. Some of these urls requires TLS where as others require SSL.

Since recent versions of TLS is considered more secure than SSLv3 some folks upgraded their application servers to use TLS while others are still configured to use SSL.

**Does HtmlUnit let you specify the protocol that you want it to use while fetching the page ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using `setSSLClientProtocols` method , belonging to the `WebClient` class. Following is the sample code snippet:

```
WebClient webClient;
BrowserVersion myBrowser = BrowserVersion.CHROME;
webClient = new WebClient(myBrowser);
webClient.getOptions().setSSLClientProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1" });
```